# Number of surjective(onto) functions

Tags: combinatorics

If a function is defined from $A \to B$ where $A=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7 \}$ and $B=\{a,b,c\}$, then find number of surjective (onto) functions from $A\to B$.

I wrote answer using inclusion-exclusion principle as
$3^7-\binom{3}{1} \cdot 2^7+ \binom{3}{2} \cdot 1^7$

Is my answer correct?

Comment: Yes, absolutely.  Nice work.

Comment: I don't blame you for not including the term $-\binom{3}{3}\cdot 0^7$ as well but it is worth keeping it in the back of your mind just to make sure that it is clear why a similar formula will work for counting the number of surjections from $\emptyset$ to $\emptyset$ (*remembering that in the context of combinatorics we say $0^0=1$*).

Comment: @JMoravitz Can $\phi$ to $\phi$ to be termed as surjective function?

Comment: Yes, absolutely.  All of the requirements are vacuously fulfilled.  Also, use \emptyset instead of \phi to denote the empty set.

Comment: @JMoravitz So $\emptyset$ to $\emptyset$ will also be an equivalence relation?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The Inclusion-Exclusion Principle can be used to show that the number of surjective functions $f:[k] \to [n]$ is equal to:
$$ \sum_{i = 0}^n \binom{n}{i}(-1)^i (n-i)^k $$

Note that the number of such surjective functions is also equal to $n! \cdot S(k,n)$, where $S(k,n)$ is the Stirling number of the second kind.